# Reading a text file and converting string to float

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

I have a text file called "foo.txt", with a list of numbers, one on each line, for example:

```
0.094195
0.216867
0.326396
0.525739
0.592552
0.600219
0.637459
0.642935
0.662651
0.657174
0.683461
```

I now want to read these numbers into a Python list. My code to do this is as follows:

```
x = []
file_in = open('foo.dat', 'r')
for y in file_in.read().split('\n'):
    x.append(float(y))
```

But this gives me the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a blank line at the end of your file?

Comment: You should `print(y)` before your `x.append(float(y))` line to see what value is failing to be converted.

Comment: Why do you `split('\n')`? ... let it `split()`

Comment: Please do not use the anti pattern of `for y in file_in.read().split('\n'):` Just do `for y in file_in:` to iterate over a text file line-by-line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**:

commented by [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau):
you can also use `if y:` to eliminate `None` or empty string.

**Original Answer:**

It fails due to you are using newline character as a separator, therefore the last element is empty string

you can add `y.isdigit()` to check whether y is numeric.

```
x = []
file_in = open('sample.csv', 'r')
for y in file_in.read().split('\n'):
    if y.isdigit():
        x.append(float(y))
```

OR

you can change `read().split("\n")` to `readlines()`

OR

remove the leading/trailing characters from y. it handles the lines with extra whitespaces

```
for y in file_in:
    trimed_line = y.strip()  # leading or trailing characters are removed
```

Comment: Could also say `if y:`, `append(float(y))`.

Comment: @martineau cannot agree more!  eliminate  `None` or empty string

Answer (score 3):

How about this approach:

```
x = []
with open('foo.dat', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line: #avoid blank lines
            x.append(float(line.strip()))
```

Or:

```
with open('foo.dat', 'r') as f:
    lines = (line.strip() for line in f if line)
    x = [float(line) for line in lines]
```

Finally more compact:

```
with open('foo.dat', 'r') as f:
    x = [float(line.strip()) for line in f if line]
```

This way you don't have to worry about blank lines and you make proper conversion from `string` to `float`

Answer (score 1):

Usually files has empty line at the end so probably you're trying to cast empty string to float.

Instead of `file_in.read().split('\n')` you could use:

```
for line in file_in.readlines():
  x.append(float(line))
```

Method `readlines` returns list of all lines from given file and skips last empty line if present.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the default float function

```
>>> float("1.1")
1.1
```

You could also try using the python try else statement which will run the code until it catches a error and runs a else statement.

```
try:
   try_this(whatever that might bring up a error)
except SomeException as exception:
   #Handle exception
else:
   return something
```

There might be a possibility that there is a blank line end of the file which might create errors. Try using the try else statement because of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think You string like this :
'0.1111, 0.1111' or other

```
file_in = open('foo.dat', 'r')
for y in file_in.readlines()[0]:
    x.append(float(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to decide whether the string you're parsing is a number or not. Based on this question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python) you can do that this way:

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

x = []
file_in = open('filename.dat', 'r')
for y in file_in.read().split('\n'):
    if is_number(y):
        x.append(float(y))
file_in.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

Note : reedline() is a string,   reedlines() is a list

```
file_in = open('foo.dat', "r")
r  =  file_in.readlines()
file_in.close()
l = 0
x = []
while l < len(r) :
    floating = float(r[l])
    x.append(floating)
    l += 1
```